# Given a string S, return the "reversed" string where all chars that are not a letter stay in the same place, and all letters reverse their positions

Tags: javascript

I've spent a while on this problem and would prefer to make this work without having to redo the problem with a different method. I understand it's not returning the '!' because of the length of the index I set it to but I'm honestly stump on how I can edge case this or something.

```
var reverseOnlyLetters = function(S) {
    let result = [];
    const letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    let sArr = S.split('')
    for (let i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
        if (sArr[i].match(/[A-Z]/gi)) {
            result.push(sArr[i])
        }
    }
    result = result.reverse()
    let other = S.split('');
    console.log(result); //[ 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a' ]
    console.log(other) //[ 'a', 'b', '-', 'c', 'd' ]
    for (j = 0; j < other.length; j++) {
        if (!letters.includes(other[j]) && letters.includes(result[j])) {
            result.splice(j,0,other[j])
        }
    }
return result.join('');
};

console.log(reverseOnlyLetters("Test1ng-Leet=code-Q!")) //"Qedo1ct-eeLg=ntse-T!"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the final loop, you're iterating over the original input string and you want to insert the symbol values into the reversed `result` string, composed of letters:

```
for (j = 0; j < other.length; j++) {
    if (!letters.includes(other[j]) && letters.includes(result[j])) {
        // problem above:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        result.splice(j,0,other[j])
    }
}
```

But when you want to do this, the letters won't include `result[j]` - just remove that, and your code will work. You don't care about what (reversed characters) `result` contains at that point, you want to replace the value at `other` index being iterated over regardless.

```js
var reverseOnlyLetters = function(S) {
  let result = [];
  const letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  let sArr = S.split('')
  for (let i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
    if (sArr[i].match(/[A-Z]/gi)) {
      result.push(sArr[i])
    }
  }
  result = result.reverse()
  let other = S.split('');
  // console.log(result); //[ 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a' ]
  // console.log(other) //[ 'a', 'b', '-', 'c', 'd' ]
  for (j = 0; j < other.length; j++) {
    if (!letters.includes(other[j])) {
      result.splice(j, 0, other[j])
    }
  }
  return result.join('');
};

console.log(reverseOnlyLetters("Test1ng-Leet=code-Q!")) //"Qedo1ct-eeLg=ntse-T!"
```

I think a clearer way to approach this would be to first get an array of all letter characters (like you're doing), then just use a regular expression to match letters in the original string and replace them with `.pop`ped values from the array:

```js
var reverseOnlyLetters = function(s) {
  const letters = s.match(/[a-z]/gi) || [];
  return s.replace(/[a-z]/gi, () => letters.pop());
};

console.log(reverseOnlyLetters("Test1ng-Leet=code-Q!")) //"Qedo1ct-eeLg=ntse-T!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if an answer is already given, here an easy solution without regex:

```js
let str = 'Test1ng-Leet=code-Q!';

const isLetter = (c) => c.toLowerCase() !== c.toUpperCase();
// extract letter character
let letters = [...str].filter(c => isLetter(c));
// recreate a reversed string
let reversed = [...str].map((c) => isLetter(c) ? letters.pop() : c).join('');

console.log(str);
console.log(reversed);
```